# Optimisation in R: Creating an exam schedule (ompr, ROI ?)

Tags: r, optimization, dplyr, ompr

I'm scheduling an exam for a course (using R).

I have 36 students, which all need to be fitted with time-slots to 8 teachers on the exam day (1:1 exams).

Each student or teacher can obviously only be in one place at a time.

How do I run an optimisation to find a solution using the least amount of time slots?

```
# Teachers
examiners <- c(seq(from=1, to=8, by= 1))

#students
students <- c(seq(from=1, to=36))
```

Some packages of interest: `ompr`, `ROI`?

Many thanks!

Comment: If each teacher supervises one student so that there can be 8 students supervised at any one time then clearly we have ceiling(36/8) time slots so no optimization routines are needed.

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly you could do: `x <- matrix(rep(1:36, 8), ncol = 8, byrow = TRUE)` and then rename the columns `colnames(x) <- paste("Teacher", LETTERS[1:8], sep = "_")` and rows `rownames(x) <- paste("Session", 1:36, sep = "_")`